# $form_state for an autocomplete callback

Tags: 6, forms, ajax

I'm trying to get the value of `$form_state` for my autocomplete textfield.

Basically, I have a search textfield and checkboxes to restrict the autocomplete.  What would be the best way of passing the checkbox values to the autocomplete?

Answer (score 2):

The autocomplete callback just gets the string that needs to be auto-completed.
In your case, the only solution I can think of is that the checkboxes use an AJAX callback that is used to set a value the autocomplete function can then access.